# Phabricator Repositories

Tags: header, repository, phabricator

when I success config the Repositories 
but it start has error;
the error is:

**Unable to Retrieve History
Ref "HEAD" is ambiguous or does not exist.**

**Unable to Retrieve Paths
Ref "HEAD" is ambiguous or does not exist.**

Answer (score 2):

This just means the repository is empty. We should show a better error message, but empty repositories were rare until we added repository hosting. This message will go away once you make some commits.

You can follow this task for progress on fixing this to say "This repository is empty.":

https://secure.phabricator.com/T1493